# Node.js read json from google api

Tags: node.js

i try to get google suggestion from this url `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=bob&client=firefox`

when i run the url i get this result : `["bob",["bobby shmurda","bob marley","bobbi kristina","bobbi brown","bobbi kristina brown","bob dylan","bob evans","bobby hurley","bob\u0027s burgers","bob seger"]]`

in node.js i used request , heres my code :

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?q=bob&client=firefox';
 request(url,function(error, response, result){
    if(!error){
    console.log(result);

    }

 });
```

until now everythings work fine
as you can see my output is an array with two values, in above code when i try to get `result[1]`instead of show array its just show a `"`.
i dont know why this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably because you get a String and not a JSON.
try JSON.parse

```
result = JSON.parse(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to parse it first

```
var json_data = JSON.parse(result);
```